# ElasticSearch Java Transport Client NoNodeAvailableException on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, elasticsearch, ubuntu-14.04

I am running **Elasticsearch v. 2.3.2**, using Java 7.  Following is the printout from `curl http://172.31.11.83:9200`:

```
{
  "name" : "ip-172-31-11-83",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
      "number" : "2.3.2",
      "build_hash" : "b9e4a6acad4008027e4038f6abed7f7dba346f94",
      "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-21T16:03:47Z",
      "build_snapshot" : false,
      "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
    },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

... and I am using the following in my Java code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**I have ports 9200 and 9300 open in my firewall rules** for my ES server, and can successfully execute said Java code from my laptop (Mac OSX).  Following is the code snippet that starts off the process (this works fine):

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
        esClient =TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new 
                InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("172.31.11.83"), 9300)));
```

Then later, I try to issue an index request (this fails when I run the code on **Ubuntu 14.04**:

```
adminClient = esClient.admin().indices();
IndicesExistsResponse response = adminClient.exists(request).actionGet();
```

My **elasticsearch.yml** file contains the following network settings:

```
network.bind_host: 0
network.publish_host: 172.31.11.83
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
```

I have also tried with `network.bind_host: 172.31.11.83` to no avail.  Using `curl`, I can get to port 9200 from all  machines.  **The cluster name reported by curl is "elasticsearch"**.

When I start ES, I see the following in the **elasticsearch.log**:

```
publish_address {172.31.11.83:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
```

And yet, the exception I get is as follows:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{172.31.11.83}{172.31.11.83:9300}]]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:283)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:336)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1178)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.exists(AbstractClient.java:1198)
```

Again, this exact code works from my local machine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your ES server hosted on Amazon EC2?

Comment: Do you confirm that this is a standalone ES install on a vanilla EC2 instance and you're not using [Amazon's Managed Elasticsearch](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) service (which doesn't support TCP communication)?

Comment: @Val, yes, I created the instance with a stock Ubuntu 14.04 AMI and built the ES config with Ansible.  The Security Group is confirmed to work as well, as I have gotten the code above to work from my laptop through VPN to our VPC using an IP on the same subnet as the other EC2 instances that cannot connect with said code.

Answer (score 0):

Having identical issue..

Upgraded elastic from 1.7 to 2.3.2 on same AWS kit

Ubunto 14.0.4

Elastic binding transport on 9300 as before

Security group has port open (not changed)

Now remote clients cannot connect via transport layer - same error as above.

The only thing that has changed in my setup is the version of Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved this. It appears 2.3.2 doesn't default TCP bind in same way as 1.7.0

I  had to set this in my elasticsearch.yml :

network.bind_host: {AWS private IP address)